# How to display Property Status title in Property Details view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a PropertyStatus table and Property Table. In the Property Table, PropertyStatus is the foreign Key table. I want to display PropertyStatus title in PropertyController details page using PropertyDetailsVM. I am using Asp.Net Core 3.1. I have done all the things but stucked here.

```
  //PropertyStatus.cs
  public class PropertyStatus
    {
        public PropertyStatus()
        {
            Properties = new Collection<Property>();

        }
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    }
  
  //Property.cs
   public class Property
    {
        public Property()
        {
            PropertyGalleries = new Collection<PropertyGallery>();

        }
        public int Id{get;set;}

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public PropertyStatus PropertyStatus { get; set; }        
        public int PropertyStatusId { get; set; }

    }
     

    //PropertyController.cs
     [Route("property/{id}/{*slug}")]
     public ActionResult Details(int id, string slug)
       {
         var property = _propertyRepository.GetById(id);
              
            if (property == null)
                return NotFound();
    
    
                var viewModel = new PropertyDetailsVM
                {
                    Property = property,
                    Id = property.Id,
                    Title = property.Title,
                    Slug = property.Slug,
                    PropertyStatus=property.PropertyStatus
                }
        }
        
    //PropertyDetailsVM
    public class PropertyDetailsVM
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Slug {get; set; }        
        public Property Property { get; set; }
        public PropertyStatus PropertyStatus { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, the PropertyStatus and Property class was configured one-to-many relationships. If that is the case, when query the property, you can use the Include method to load its PropertyStatus via the navigation property.

Please refer the following sample:

```
//PropertyStatus.cs
public class PropertyStatus
{
    public PropertyStatus()
    {
        Properties = new List<Property>();

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

}

//Property.cs
public class Property
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public PropertyStatus PropertyStatus { get; set; }
    public int PropertyStatusId { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    //private readonly IDbContextProvider _dbProvider;
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context,  IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        //_dbProvider = provider;
        Configuration = configuration;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {  
        //required using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        //you can check your _propertyRepository.GetById method, and sue the include method
        var property = _context.Properties.Include(c => c.PropertyStatus).Where(c => c.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (property == null)
            return NotFound();

        var viewModel = new PropertyDetailsVM
        {
            Property = property,
            Id = property.Id,
            Title = property.Title,
            Slug = property.Slug,
            PropertyStatus = property.PropertyStatus
        }; 
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Then in the view page: use the following code to display the property status information:

```
@model Core3_1MVC.Models.PropertyDetailsVM

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
 
<div> 
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Slug)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Slug)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
           PropertyStatus Title:
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyStatus.Title)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information, you can refer the following articles:

[EF Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

[Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)